# Can I disable related list hover links on a specific page?

Tags: user-interface, salesforce

Like it asks in the title, can I disable related list hover links on a specific page? I have a standard page of a few fields and a related list. This results in an entirely useless related list hover link. I would like to remove it just from this page but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change your organization's user interface settings:

1. Click Your Name > Setup > Customize > User Interface.
2. deselect **Enable Related List Hover Links**
3. Click Save.

Those steps are to set disabled **Related List Hover Links** in all your tabs. In addition, you can to disable it for one Tab(Object) using *VisualForce*

[Complete info here](http://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_ui_settings.htm#HoverLinks)

:)